# Deep linking in iOS 10 not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

I have an app that relies on deep linking using a custom scheme `://appName` for some user email verification. The way it currently works is:

1. User enters email in app and hits send
2. Email is sent to user, user taps on "activate" button
3. Button opens valid website url which then redirects to deep link url, i.e ://appName/auth/tokenId

All was good, and this worked flawlessly on iOS 9 devices, but iOS 10 seemed to break it.

**After further investigation:**

appName://id=123 opens in iOS9, but in iOS10 safari displays that “the url can’t be shown” for the exact same URL.
They will both work however for the URL scheme alone (appName://)

You can even test this on your devices/simulator to see. Perhaps the change is in safari?

**More investigation**:

Almost sure its related to Safari.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually tracked down this issue and got a response from the CEO of Branch. He said:

> Ah interesting find! I just tested a few ways and **it seems to reject
>   typed-in URI schemes with a deep link host & path**, but you can still
>   trigger them in JS and click them on page. You just can't type it in
>   for some reason.

So beware of this if you are using deep linking in such a way on iOS 10!

I personally ended up just giving the direct deep link URL in the email, rather than embedding a redirect in a nice button. Something like this `appName://gotoHere/here`